# odoo xml t-value= html tag

Tags: xml, odoo

I want to send html tag in t-value as:

```
<template id="module.content">
  <div>
    <t t-value="img_src"/>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="module.content1">
  <t t-set="img_src" t-value="<img src='module/static/img/image01.png' alt=''/>"/>
  <t t-call="module.content"/>
</template>
```

but i get an error

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Unescaped '<' not allowed in attributes values, line 109, column 37
```

is there any way to send html tags in t-value

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a syntax error?

```
  <t t-set="img_src" t-value="<img src='module/static/img/image01.png' alt=''/>"/>
```

should be

```
  <t t-set="img_src" t-value="<img src='module/static/img/image01.png' alt='' "/>
```

Comment: it is syntax error, but the error in symbol '<'. That's a question - how to put html tags in t-value and don't get syntax error. (your example don't work, same error)